# Retrieving column with some records but not with all

Tags: sql-server

I want to retrieve all records of products to display on website, but there is a column 'BestSeller' that I want to retrieve only if there is no null in it. Means this column will be retrieved with some records but not with all. Any one know doing this with a single query?

Comment: post what you have tried so far ??

Comment: I'm new to SQL, I stuck at this point, nothing tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select * From Table Where      bestseller is not null
```

Comment: Then it won't retrieve "all" records.

Comment: If you need all records, what exactly do You want to happen if bestsellers is null?

Comment: I don't want to retrieve BestSeller column for that specific case (when it is null)  but I need other columns for the same record. And for other records I want all columns.

Comment: This is not possible, but why not just ignore the null?

Comment: There is almost no cost for retrieving the colomn, so its not a performance issue.

Comment: Okay means it is not possible, Thanks You.